# Why Am I getting an object with action observer property from selector using withLatestFrom operation in effect?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-selectors

The "res" value is an object, that is not retrieving the data related to the selector, is working in other places, but in the effect is getting this object. Why is happening this?

```
constructor(
      private serviceStore: Store<DataState>,
) {

  searchForLatest$ = createEffect(() =>
      this._actions.pipe(
          ofType<GetLatestRequestService>(GetLatestData),
          withLatestFrom(({ id }) => 
             this.serviceStore.select(getlatestData(id)),
          mergeMap(res => {
              


 actionsObserver: { 
      closed: false,
      hasError: false,
      isStopped: false,
      observers: [SkipSubscriber],
      thrownError: null,
      _isScalar: false,
}
operator: {
      compare: undefined
      keySelector: undefined
}
reducerManager: {
      closed: false
      dispatcher: DevtoolsDispatcher {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, 
      isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
      hasError: false
      initialState: undefined
      isStopped: false
      observers: [MapSubscriber]
      reducerFactory: (reducers, initialState) => {…}
      reducers: {uiContext: ƒ, parties: ƒ, user: ƒ, organizationsDetail: ƒ, activeRoute: ƒ, …}
      thrownError: null
      _isScalar: false
      _value: (state, action) =>
}
Source: {
     actionsObserver: ActionsSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, 
     isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
     operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
     reducerManager: ReducerManager {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(1), closed: false, 
     isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
     source: Store {_isScalar: false, actionsObserver: ActionsSubject, reducerManager: 
     ReducerManager, source: Observable}
     _isScalar: false
```

}
_isScalar: false

Comment: It seems you're not correctly applying `withLatestFrom` that should be used with an observable like `withLatestFrom(anObservable$)`. Rephrase your request, what is the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: This is an observable this.serviceStore.select(getlatestData(id)), I need to retrieve the latest data from that selector, the problem was the operator in the previous approaches in effects the withLatestFrom was enough get the data from store.

Answer (score 0):

The effects in v13 updated the approach to retrieve the latest data from a selector, I need to use the ***concatLatestFrom*** operator to get the data.

```
@Injectable()
export class CollectionEffects {
  addBookToCollectionSuccess$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CollectionApiActions.addBookSuccess),
        concatLatestFrom(action => this.store.select(fromBooks.getCollectionBookIds)),
        tap(([action, bookCollection]) => {
          if (bookCollection.length === 1) {
            window.alert('Congrats on adding your first book!');
          } else {
            window.alert('You have added book number ' + bookCollection.length);
          }
        })
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
   );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store: Store<fromBooks.State>
  ) {}
}
```

Note: For performance reasons, use a flattening operator like concatLatestFrom to prevent the selector from firing until the correct action is dispatched.